# python asyncio as_completed

Tags: python, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

Объясните пожалуйста, когда нужно применять `asyncio.as_completed` и в чем различие от подобных функций. Просто есть функции `asyncio.wait` и `asyncio.gather` и не понимаю надобность `asyncio.as_completed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `asyncio.gather` самый простой вариант - запускает все и ждет пока все будут готовы. Используй когда нужно получить все результаты для дальнейшей работы.
- `asyncio.as_completed` выдает по одной задаче по мере готовности. Очень простой по синтаксису вариант. Используй для вывода или обработки результата по мере выполнения.
- `asyncio.wait` сложный по синтаксису, но универсальный вариант - через него можно получить и все сразу и по одной, но чтоб сделать из него простой цикл нужно написать довольно много кода.

Comment: То есть `asyncio.as_completed` ведёт себя как генератор?

Comment: Да, генератор, выдает корутины, в которых установлен результат и их можно сразу эвэйтить